# How to scale an image so that it is always 75% of the screen size within an Android RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, imageview, android-relativelayout

I have an image in a RelativeLayout that I want scale up and down in order to take up the same percentage of space regardless of what screen size the user has. I want the image to be approximately 75% of the screen's width, whether the app is being viewed on a tablet or on a mobile phone.

I am struggling to figure out the best way to achieve this because it seems that `layout_weight` doesn't work in relative layouts. What is the best way to achieve a percentage width in this scenario?

Comment: `it seems that layout_weight doesn't work in relative layouts` - It doesn't. It only works in **LinearLayouts**. And only for **ONE dimension at a time**.

Answer (score 0):

try playing with the margin right and left

```
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
```

change the 10dp according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong. The Layout_weight is still the best way.
Just make a LinearLayout in the RelativeLayout. Then let this LinearLayout match parent width and wrap content for its height. Now after putting your image in this Layout, put something else like another LinearLayout in that. Now use Layout_weight to have 75% of the screen width.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:src="my_source"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Now Just enjoy it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! With a little bit of tweaking I have this kind of working. It seems to work for some devices but not for others. Also, the image is now centered vertically on my page, but i want it sitting at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I agree LinearLayout is the way to go:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout_75_percent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".75" >


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout_25_percent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25" >

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

```
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImageView);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (metrics.widthPixels*0.75), RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        mImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```